# Rancher can't find link when net=host

Tags: docker, docker-compose, rancher

I have a service discovery and a client registering to this server in Rancher.
It goes like this:

```
eureka-server:
  ports:
  - 8761:8761/tcp
  labels:
    io.rancher.container.pull_image: always
    io.rancher.container.start_once: 'true'
  tty: true
  image: luizkowalski/eureka-server
  stdin_open: true
  net: host
edge-server:
  ports:
  - 8080:8080/tcp
  labels:
    io.rancher.container.pull_image: always
    io.rancher.container.start_once: 'true'
  tty: true
  image: luizkowalski/edge-server
  links:
  - eureka-server:discovery
  stdin_open: true
  net: host
```

Given the link, I should be able to connect to `eureka-server` using the hostname `discovery`, like `http://discovery:8761/eureka` but I'm getting

```
10/28/2016 2:04:55 PMCaused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: discovery
10/28/2016 2:04:55 PM   at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1280) ~[na:1.8.0_92-internal]
10/28/2016 2:04:55 PM   at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1192) ~[na:1.8.0_92-internal]
10/28/2016 2:04:55 PM   at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1126) ~[na:1.8.0_92-internal]
10/28/2016 2:04:55 PM   at org.apache.http.impl.conn.SystemDefaultDnsResolver.resolve(SystemDefaultDnsResolver.java:45) ~[httpclient-4.5.2.jar!/:4.5.2]
10/28/2016 2:04:55 PM   at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.resolveHostname(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:262) ~[httpclient-4.5.2.jar!/:4.5.2]
10/28/2016 2:04:55 PM   at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:161) ~[httpclient-4.5.2.jar!/:4.5.2]
10/28/2016 2:04:55 PM   at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:144) ~[httpclient-4.5.2.jar!/:4.5.2]
```

It works when I use the network as `managed` in Rancher, but as a result, my service discovery expose my internal ips to the load balancer (`172.xxx.xxx.xx`) and I'm not able to call my registered services
is there any config missing yet?

Answer (score 1):

In order to get access to Rancher DNS, which provides the link name resolution, you need the label `io.rancher.container.dns:true` added to the server with net: host.